# update dialog box's content when icon is click inside ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying open a dialog when an icon inside `ListView` is clicked. The dialog is a `AlertDialog` which contains few `TextViews` that shows information based on the List Item clicked. Each List Item will show different information inside dialog box when clicked.

the problem is when an icon is clicked i am calling `showDialog(INFO_DIALOG_ENYTY);` and TextView inside dialog are updated only once as dialog is created inside onCreateDialog.

But I want to update TextView's contect which is inside dialog every time i click on List Item icon.

or if anyone else has another option to use instead of dialog then please suggest as my soul purpose is to show information when icon is clicked inside ListView

Answer (score 0):

on click event check for the alertbuilder instance if the instance is not null then set text to the textview and show the dialog using `showdialog(0)` method. if the instance is not null then create the dialog

### See the sample example

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int counter = 0;

    Builder myAlertDialog;
    View entryView;
    TextView dialogTextview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }

    public OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            ++counter;
            startDialog("Clicked=" + counter);

        }

    };

    private void startDialog(String message) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        entryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.mytest, null);
        dialogTextview = (TextView) entryView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        if (myAlertDialog == null) {
            myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            myAlertDialog.setView(entryView);

            myAlertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to exit the application?");
            myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        // do something when the button is clicked
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            System.out.println("...yes button is clicked..");
                            arg0.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

            myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        // do something when the button is clicked
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            System.out.println("...clicked no...");
                            arg0.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = myAlertDialog.create();

            alert.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);

            myAlertDialog.show();
        } else {
            dialogTextview.setText(message);
            System.out.println("...settext in dialog...");
            myAlertDialog.setView(entryView);
            myAlertDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```